# Record THREEJS animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-mediarecorder

I want to be able to record 4k videos of my threejs scene at 60 fps. I have tried ccapture and canvas.captureStream(). They have unreliable effect on my frame rate and hence there are a lot of frame drops. The scene is able to play smoothly at 60 fps but when we add mediaRecorder (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) the fps drops as low as 4fps. Can anyone provide any solution for the issue?

Comment: You need to better explain why the CCapture aproach is not working for you, as it is designed to solve exactly the problem you seem to be having. "Frame drops" should never be happening, as it doesn't record the frames in real time. What method are you using to calculate elapsed time in your frame handler?

Comment: The problem with CCapture is it requires controlled time update. Since we have videoTexture in our scene we can not update video time to +.016 to get every frame. As it takes as long as 3 second to get updated and render on screen. Also I was unable to record audio with ccapture. CaptureStream increases "update layer tree" footprint in the performance tab and slows the recording.

Comment: Thank you for adding that. Streaming video & audio recording are both great examples of a use case that CCapture doesn't handle. Unfortunately, given this use case, I don't have an answer to your specific question. I'd personally just a separate machine with a 4k video capture card (hdmi capture), so the three.js machine can do it's thing with full performance.

Comment: Might this be a bit too ambitious of a task? It's kind of a miracle to even have 3d running in the browser at 60fps. Could you do this effectively with native c++/opengl, given your input, and the fact that you are already rendering a video?

My approach to this would be to take a snapshot of all the inputs during some interaction, and then replay that while recording. Advance state after recording a frame.

Comment: @Paul-Jan this requires the client to have this hardware, in which case javascript and webgl are probably not the right tools to even be doing this. I'm trying to understand the use case here, because it does seem somewhat odd. You can't possibly rely on all the clients to have the capability of doing this.

Comment: I want to make it run on my 8GB RAM system on chrome browser without the use of external hardware. I am able to achieve 8 fps for 4k videos and I slow down the video 8 times to capture and play it faster to get the final object. What I don't understand is what is slowing down the computer as the performance tab of chrome browser is showing "others" to take most of the time. I can share performance snapshot if anyone wants to check out.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your requirements, but if you're just capturing video, why not use a system-level screen recorder (FRAPS, OBS Studio, Camtasia, etc.). You can designate your screen region so you don't capture the browser window bits, and I believe most capture software will also allow you to record audio/voice at the same time.

Comment: I imagine it's the uploading of video data to the gpu.

Comment: I tried FRAPS but wasn't able to run it maybe I will check it again. But I only want the canvas to be recorded while I have freedom to work on other windows and also resize/re-position by browser. So FRAPS will not be the correct choice for me. I am using canvas.captureStream() currently. The basic issue is that it slows down system performance. I want to know what heavy computations is it doing to just capture the stream. And can we avoid any of those to increase performance. Also capturing stops on window blur event which is part of another issue.

Comment: Are you providing a frame rate to `captureStream`?

Comment: I have tried with and without providing frame rate but still the performance is way below desired 60 fps.

Comment: 4K 60FPS realtime video capture and compression via Javascript is currently not possible. The bottle neck is the compression. On chrome recording a frame at a time, holding the 3D update until you have encoded the frame, Thus you record at a slow frame rate but playback is normal. Also Chrome has native compression for webp image format which you can use to speed up the webM encoding. Your only challenge is memory, for long recording you will have to record parts saving when memory is low, then join post record with some video editing app.

Comment: Do we have a way to hook videoplayback speed to this slow frame rate. Spite did an awesome job hooking requestTimeOut, setTimeOut, etc in his library [ccapture](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/blob/master/src/CCapture.js ). But it was unable to slow down the video playbackrate.